# Problem with fgets in program using threads

Tags: c, multithreading

i've been trying and searching to fix a problem in my program for several hours, and i haven't found any solution. My problem is the following: i have a program receiving queries to be executed, this program can take the queries as redirection or by input. When it's by input, the program needs to stop when user do CTRL+C or CTRL+D, before quitting the program, it needs to save the database. So i used fgets for reading queries to do something like:

```
void* queries_(void* prm){
   while(fgets(buffer, 64, stdin)){..}
}
```

I used threads to speed up queries processing when we pass a file to the program by redirection. This is when i got a problem. I added threads to the main function calling this queries_processing function like this.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, stop_);
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, queries_, &db);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, queries_, &db);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    
    // save database ...
}
```

But this is the part that i didn't understand, when user do CTRL+D, the while loop in queries_ stops for both threads and we get back to the main function and execute what is after the pthread_join. And for the ctrl+C, i created a function handler called stop_ where i fclose(stdin) to stop the while loop. But when i call this handler, the program get stuck, nothing happens, and the insturctions after the pthread_join isn't executed.

Any ideas what's causing that?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but you could consider using a single producer thread that calls fgets and then pushes the lines into a queue for two consumer threads to process.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try to implement that.

Comment: My guess is that the answer to your question is that fgets and fclose are attempting to acquire the same mutex. To solve this, you need a version of fgets that can be interrupted from the main thread, in the same manner you can interrupted a wait on a condition variable. You may look into async io libraries.

Comment: Another problem is that even if the `fclose()` succeeds, attempting to read from a closed stream is undefined behavior.  It's not guaranteed to fail cleanly; it may crash, or spin, or deadlock, or do any other undesirable thing.  You need a different design.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers i fixed my problem by creating one thread to read queries and send work to other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call fgetc/fgets/fscanf on the same file handle (in this cases stdin) from multiple threads at the same time. Your program behavior is unspecified due to an unremovable race condition in the kernel.

Try using one thread to read from stdin and passing the line it read to the next available worker thread.